# I'm having trouble making my model look good with a small amount of faces

Tags: modeling, mesh, subdivision-surface

Here a pistol that I'm trying to model for a game.

[image: This is the reference]

I watched a video where a guy made a whole rifle with way less faces than I have and his looked really good, while mine still doesn't look that great. I know part of it is just experience but there has to be something that I'm doing wrong that could be corrected.

Obviously there are a lot of unnecessary faces but I had to subdivide my model because there were some parts of it that were just looking horrible.  If you want to give me some tips that would be great or if you want to just link me to a really detailed tutorial that might help my situation.

Anything would help.

[[image: Gun topology]
[image: Object mode]

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to learn about working with *Subdivision Surface* based meshes and adding control loops to control subdivision.

Try working with a lower poly version of your model as base mesh and add details only as needed dynamically with a *Subsurf* modifier on top.

[image: Subsurf gun]

That not only make modeling a lot easier and manageable, because there are a lot less vertex around to control, but also reduce polygons considerably.

You can control the number of subdivisions dynamically before exporting, without having to rebuild your model from scratch.

See tutorials about [Blender Subsurface Modifier](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=vid&q=blender%20subsurf)